Hölder Continuity and Exponential Map in a Banach Algebra
I have a family of elements $A_t$ in a Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$, where the map $t \mapsto A_t$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous. Specifically, this means there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for all $t, s$ in the domain:
$$
\|A_t - A_s\| \leq C |t - s|^\alpha.
$$
Given this setup, I am interested in the behavior of the exponential map. Define $A_{ab} = A_b - A_a$. I would like to establish the following inequality:
$$
\|\exp(A_{ab}) - \exp(A_{ac})\exp(A_{cb})\| \leq \text{cst} \cdot (b-a)^{2\alpha},
$$
where $a \leq c \leq b$ and $\text{cst}$ is some constant independent of $a$, $b$, and $c$.
I found this inequality mentioned in Example 3 of the paper "A Non-commutative Sewing Lemma" by Bailleul and Riedel, but the details are not fully explained. Could someone help me understand why this inequality holds, or provide a proof or counterexample? Any insights into the role of the BCH formula or commutator estimates in this context would also be appreciated.
